# Compare List with different number of items

Tags: python, list, comparison, compare, contains

How can I do this?

```
A = ['fish', 'banana', 'old pajamas', 'Mutton', 'Beef', 'Trout']
B = ['fish', 'banana', 'old pajamas']

B in A = True
A in B = False
```

I tried the 'in' comparator, but it returns False in both cases because it's checking if the List B is inside the List A and not the items of B in A.

Is there a easy way to do this beside using a very long if statement like this:

```
if B[0] == A[0] and B[1] == A[1] and B[2] == A[2]: 
    return True
else: return False
```

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous, the first part suggests using `in` but the second part suggests comparing elements like-for-like by index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [8]: all(a==b for a,b in zip(A,B))
Out[8]: True
```

is equivalent to

```
if B[0] == A[0] and B[1] == A[1] and B[2] == A[2]: 
    return True
else: return False
```

since [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) terminates when there are no more elements in the shorter of `A` or `B`:

```
In [9]: zip(A, B)
Out[9]: [('fish', 'fish'), ('banana', 'banana'), ('old pajamas', 'old pajamas')]
```

---

If, on the other hand, you wish to test if all the elements of `A` are in `B`, then you are looking for a subset relationship. If you convert `A` and `B` to sets, then you could use its `<=` operator:

```
In [12]: set(B) <= set(A)
Out[12]: True
```

since `B` is a subset of `A`.

```
In [13]: set(A) <= set(B)
Out[13]: False
```

since `A` is not a subset of `B`.

---

Edit: As Aशwini चhaudhary points out, sets also have an [`issubset` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

```
In [42]: set(B).issubset(A)
Out[42]: True

In [43]: set(A).issubset(B)
Out[43]: False
```

Comment: Sets have a `issubset` method too: `set(B).issubset(A)`